# Why the Task Manager automatically does not start from the Startup folder at user log on?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

I want the Task Manager to be able start automatically each time when user login to the Windows. The following article describes how to [Add an app to run automatically at startup in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd):

> 1. Select the **Start** button and scroll to find the app you want to run at startup.
> 2. Right-click the app, select **More**, and then select **Open file location**. This opens the location where the shortcut to the app is
>    saved. If there isn't an option for **Open file location**, it means
>    the app can't run at startup.
> 3. With the file location open, press the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type **shell:startup**, then select **OK**.
>    This opens the **Startup** folder.
> 4. Copy and paste the shortcut to the app from the file location to the **Startup** folder.

I created shortcuts exactly according to the article above. The `FireFox`, for example, is starting without a problem, but the Task Manger don't.

My shortcut in the **Startup** folder:

[image]

> UPDATE: As you can see in the shortcut parameters the Task Manager is
> starting in the minimized mode, but I can see it icon in the System
> Tray.

I also checked proposed solutions from the following posts:

[Launch Task Manager as minimized to the tray on login](https://superuser.com/q/756298/1266966)

[Task Manager Does Not Start Every Time](https://superuser.com/q/403476/1266966)

So, my question is *“Why the Task Manager automatically does not start from the Startup folder on a user login”?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is possible to use the Task Scheduler to run the `Taskmgr.exe` at user log on. Unfortunately, when I minimize the application I don't see it icon in the System Tray area, what is required.

Therefore, I found the following solution:

1. Created a `.bat` script file with one command: `start /min /high C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe`. The /min parameter says the `Taskmgr.exe` will start minimized.
2. Create shortcut to `.bat` script file and put in under the **Startup** folder.

Now the `TaskManger` starts at user log on. It minimized and it is possible to see it icon in the System Tray area.

Comment: What is the `/high` for?

Comment: I just answered my own question, from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start: "Starts an application in the specified priority class."

Comment: @LironYahdav: Yes, it's correct. This indicate to starts the task manager in the `high` priority class.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 thing going on:

- It won't start from the Startup folder, because you can't give it admin privileges. This is a dead end.
- It won't start from Task Scheduler (correctly), because when it starts, it starts too early, there is no desktop at that time. **We need a 1s delay in Task Scheduler!**
- If you use a .bat/.cmd file, there will be a popup cmd window. **We need a VBScrip 1-liner!**

Solution:

- Create a "StartMinimizedHighpriority.vbs" in the System32 folder with this 1 line in it: `CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start /min /high " & WScript.Arguments.Item(0), 0, False`
- Create a Task Scheduler task

  - with a "1 second" delay in the Trigger
  - with "C:\Windows\System32\StartMinimizedHighpriority.vbs" as Program and "C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe" as Argument in the Action

Comment: **1)** You don't need administrator privileges to start the `taskmgr` from the _Startup_ folder both for a standalone computer and for computer controlled by the Active Directory (**AD**). Especially when computer under the AD control the network administrators can easy configure these permissions by using the group policy.

Comment: **2)** When you are using the Task Scheduler it's necessary to make some delay before starting the `taskmgr`.  For example, using  `timeout /T 3` command inside the batch file, before running the `taskmgr`. But applications from the _Startup_ folder are started by Windows when the Desktop is active. Therefore, no reason to make a delay.  **3)** When the _Run_ property for the shortcut (see the original question above) set to `Minimized` there is no `cmd` popup window. This parameter is using by many administrators to run script in background.

Comment: Yeah, shortcut in the Startup folder doesn't require a delay, and you can set minimized on the shortcut, but you can't set the admin privilege, so it won't work. It worked in the past, but currently it doesn't work on Win 11. I've spent hours fighting with it, googling some solution, nothing worked, gave up. That's why I've used the Task Scheduler.

Comment: I see. I'm using my solution on the Windows 10. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open Task Scheduler.
Click "New Task"
Set a trigger to "at startup" or "at log on".
Set an action to start `taskmgr.exe`
Set to run on highest privileges
Name your task.
Set the task to run if the user is logged on OR NOT.
Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
Enter your credentials, and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
It doesn't start in the "Startup" folder because Microsoft programmed it so system apps will not start in the "Startup" folder. If you try other system apps it won't work. Try asking in the MS help center.

Comment: Thanks! The task manager is started. Unfortunately, I did not find an option how to run it minimized state. Furthermore, when I minimize the application manually, I do not see it icon in the System Tray area, what I need.

Comment: @Jackdaw did you press the up arrow in the system tray, drag its icon and click "Hide when minimized" in the Taskmgr?

Comment: I don't have `up arrow` in the system tray: all icons are visible.