# `taskmgr.exe` The requested operation requires elevation

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, autostart

I tried to auto start the `taskmgr.exe` on the user login  by creating a shortcut of ***Task Manager*** in the startup folder, as it described on the [Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/is-it-possible-to-have-taskmanager-autostart-when/a8a56901-e91a-43fe-b6bd-0068d5a84377):

1. Open Run, type and enter `shell:appsfolder`
2. Locate Task Manager
3. Open Run again, type and enter `shell:startup`
4. Drag Task Manager from apps folder to startup folder

But I got the following error:

[image]

Is there easy way to resolve this error in the Windows 10?
Thanks

---

Windows 10 Pro 21H2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Task Manager is a special case, so it should rather be called
indirectly.

- Run `shell:startup`
- Click anywhere in the folder in the empty space and select
  *New > Text document*
- Name the file `taskmgr.bat`
- Right-click the file and select Edit
- Paste the following text :
  `start C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe`
- Save the file and exit
- Done.

---

(*Old answer - works for everything **except** the Task Manager*)

Create a shortcut instead of dragging the program :

- Run `shell:startup`
- Click anywhere in the folder in the empty space and select
  *New > Shortcut*
- Enter the location as `C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe`
- Click Next
- Accept the name of `Taskmgr.exe` by clicking Finish.
- Done.

Comment: I've rewritten the answer - better delete the previous shortcut.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but this is look like solution I found one year ago [https://superuser.com/a/1647669/1266966](https://superuser.com/a/1647669/1266966). But I trying to found a _"clean"_ solution, to understand what is the problem with this application (taskmgr). It's seems like some tuning, perhaps in registry, might be made to resolve this.  Because I have a case when I would prefer don't to create an additional script.